# why package dependencies not working even they are installed?

Tags: react-native, npm

I created a package which uses `react-native-webview` as a dependency and I published it to npm.

My steps to create and publish a package are:

1. `npm init`
2. `npm link react-native-webview`
3. `npm install react-native-webview`
4. `npm publish`

Everything worked perfectly and I successfully published my package.

However, after the installation of my package using `npm install <package_name>` in another project, when I run the project I always get this error:

> ```
> requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager
> ```

I don't know why I am getting this. I also checked the dependencies in `node_modules` folder and all are present. But when I install `react-native-webview` dependency explicitly into my project It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to native link not present in between the **UIManager** and the **JS core**

You can either run `react-native link react-native-webview` or link it [manually](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking)

Answer (score 0):

use `react-native link` command to link dependencies
run

```
npx react-native link react-native-webview
```